# List installed icon sets and themes

Tags: icons, themes

How can I see a list with the names of the different icon sets and themes I've installed in elementary OS?

I can see them listed if I use elementary-tweaks, but that app is [not maintained anymore](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+MichaelStarkweather/posts/Y8zixFDEWiv) and [not recommended by Daniel](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/38z164/what_is_the_elementary_teams_stance_on_elementary/crz5dsf), so I'm trying to avoid using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are all in one of two places, so this command should work:

```
cd /usr/share/icons 2> /dev/null && for dir in *; do if [ "$(ls $dir | grep -o -m 1 cursor)" = "" ]; then echo $dir; fi; done && cd ~/.icons 2> /dev/null && for dir in *; do if [ "$(ls $dir | grep -o -m 1 cursor)" = "" ]; then echo $dir; fi; done
```

It will show something like this:

```
App.png
cab_extract.png
cab_view.png
default
default.kde4
Faience
Faience-Azur
Faience-Claire
Faience-Ocre
gnome
hicolor
```

Comment: That command also lists cursor themes. It'd be better if those could be filtered out.

Comment: Looking at this solution I prefer to use unsupported and not recommended Tweaks...